# Python пытается удалить удаленное число из массива

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, матрицы

Есть код:

```
import numpy as np
import random
def solve_puzzle():
    a = 7
    b = 7
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    str = []
    for i in range(a):
        str.append([])
        for j in range(b):
            x = random.randint((min(numbers)), max(numbers))
            str[i].append(x)
            numbers.remove(x)
            print(x)
            
            
            

    print(np.array(str))     

solve_puzzle()
```

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы выводилась матрица из 7 строк по 7 чисел в каждой, причем числа в строке не должны повторятся. Пытался сначала добавлять число в строку, а затем удалять его из списка тех, которые нужно добавить. Однако Python выкатывает ошибку ValueError
list.remove(x): x not in list.

Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
x = random.randint((min(numbers)), max(numbers))
```

После удаления элементов из `numbers` никто вам не гарантирует, что в нём есть **любой** из элементов между минимальным и максимальным, там вполне могут быть пропуски. Пример:

```
[1, 9]
```

В этом массиве есть только минимальный элемент 1 и максимальный 9, а ничего остального между ними просто нет.

Чтобы выбрать произвольный элемент из `numbers` используйте другой метод:

```py
x = random.choice(numbers)
```

Хотя это не исправит остальные проблемы вашего алгоритма, с которыми вам ещё предстоит разобраться. Но конкретно эту проблему - исправит.